# Адреса внутри исполняемых файлов

Tags: файлы, адрес

Пусть исполняемый файл х хранится на диске. Что значит, когда об этом файле говорят "адрес какой-то инструкции" или "адрес какой-то функции"? Адрес относительно нуля? Но ведь это просто файл, он не загружен в процесс и виртуального адресного пространства еще не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от исполняемого файла. Если это какой нибудь com/bin файл, то адреса в нем соответствуют тому, что будет в ОЗУ, возможно с определенным смещением. При создании таких файлов заранее известно, какой загрузчик и по каким адресам его загрузит. Тот же com-файл грузится по смещению 100h относительно начала текущего сегмента кода. Для bin файлов начальных загрузчиков известно по каким адресам его загрузит bios.

Более сложные форматы файлов, такие как exe или elf вообще могут содержать множество секций, загружаемых в разные сегменты. При этом в самих файлах находятся относительные адреса, от начала соответствующих секций. Или идентификаторы внешних функций, для динамического связывания. А так же эти файлы содержат таблицы настройки адресов, в которых хранится информация о том, где именно и какие относительные адреса были использованы. Какие функции из каких внешних библиотек (dll/so) используются и где вызываются. Загрузчик ОС при загрузке такого файла в ОЗУ меняет относительные адреса из файла, на реальные, пользуясь таблицами настройки адресов.

Comment: Получается эти адреса нужны для удобства?

Comment: @Dwarf А вы их в каком контексте рассматриваете, о чем идет речь, когда они упоминаются ? Я бы сказал что они нужны в первую очередь загрузчику ОС, что бы правильно разместить файл в памяти.

Comment: при просмотре секций ELF файла какой-то утилитой, не помню название, она выводит адреса начала секций и их названия, вот я и хотел узнать эти адреса рассматриваются только в контексте исполняемого файла и существуют только в нем?

Answer (score 0):

Адрес почти всегда является виртуальным адресом инструкции процессора, на которой возник сбой. Для персоналок в 99% случаев - это адрес в виртуальной памяти. (Адрес относительно нуля - ну да, адрес относительно нуля вируальной памяти.) Есть утилиты и функции, которые умеют определять как загружена память, т.е. в какой диапазон адресов какой модуль загружен. По диапазону адресов можно определить модуль, а уже по модулю - определить место в файле, и если есть для файла debug-info - то можно узнать строчку кода. Некоторые инструменты умеют по адресу находить строчку кода, где возникла ошибка.

Один из примеров - borland pascal delphi си, у этих продуктов есть встроеная функция поиска ошибки по адресу (пункт меню Search - Go to address). В некоторых других средах можно програмно вычислить где возникла ошибка.

Ошибка в библиотеке (для которой нету debuginfo) может быть вызвана неправильными параметрами из основной программы, поэтому stacktrace показывает больше полезной информации, чем просто адрес сбоя. Некоторые программы создают дампы ошибок, что б разработчик мог увидеть картину сбоя - цепочку вызваных функций и их параметры.